# How can I refactor methods and add enums with On and Off values

Tags: java, selenium, appium

How can I refactor code in more readable code?

I was thinking of using Enums or fix methods that we have. I'm little bit confused how can we use Enums in this script if its necessary.

```
MobileElement button = (xpath ==//....);

//option = yes or no.
//This is for option == Yes. otherOption = Red, Blue, Black, Yellow
public boolean isYes(String option,String otherOption) {
    if (otherOption.equals("Yes") && button.getText().contains("Yes")) {
        button.click();
        clickButton(otherOption);
        return button.getText().contains("Yes");
    } else if (otherOption.equals("Yes") && button.getText().contains("No")) {
        clickButton(otherOption);
        return button.getText().contains("Yes");
    }
    return false;
}

public void clickButton(String otherOption) {

    MobileBy otherOptionClick = (MobileBy) MobileBy.ByAndroidUIAutomator
        .AndroidUIAutomator(String.format("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("
        + "new UiSelector().resourceId(\"android.ios\")"
            + ".textContains(\"%s\"))", otherOption));
    otherOptionClick.click();
    okButton.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify a few extra lines, and also add the String as constants to avoid initializing them every time:

```
private final static String YES = "Yes";
private final static String NO = "No";
private final static String ON = "On";

//option = yes or no.
//This is for option == Yes. otherOption = Red, Blue, Black, Yellow
public boolean isYes(String option,String otherOption) {
    if (otherOption.equals(YES)){
        if(button.getText().contains(YES)) {
            button.click();
            clickButton(otherOption);
            return button.getText().contains(ON);
        } else if (button.getText().contains(NO)) {
            clickButton(otherOption);
            return button.getText().contains(ON);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What if button.getText().contains(); uppercase (YES and Yes) also with just Y capital letter not the whole word. 
 Would you use this way: 
button.getText().contains("YES") || button.getText().contains("Yes")

Comment: You could use button.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(YES)

Comment: but Buttons text ends with Yes. for ex:  burronText  =  Logs: Yes 
buttonText = Logs: YES. The text is not just yes or no so i used contains() or endsWith()

Comment: You can use the Apache Commons library and do: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(button.getText(), YES);